# Can not invoke error in postrequest in swift

Tags: ios, swift

code:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"http://../projects/quotes/index.php/synchronization/get_daily_quotes")!)
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        var err: NSError?

        var params = ["user_id":"1","number_of_quotes":"2","category_ids":"1"]as NSDictionary

        request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err) // This Line fills the web service with required parameters.
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var err1: NSError?
             var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(strData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

            println("json2 :\(jsonResult)")

            if((err != nil)) {
                println(err!.localizedDescription)
            }
            else {
                var success = jsonResult["success"] as? Int
                println("Succes: \(success)")
            }
        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

I am trying send postrequest with json arguments.it gives me error as "Cannot invoke 'JSONObjectWithData' with an argument list of type '(NSString?, options: NSJSONReadingOptions, error: nil)".Why i am getting this error?any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

creates a string, not NSData, so you just have to invoke `JSONObjectWithData` like this:

```
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
```

Comment: @user3823935 in this case do not forget to accept the answer.